# Why is the triangle being rendered with rough edges and not smooth edges? Metal, Swift, Xcode

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I am using this code to render the "Hello Triangle" triangle. On my iPhone, though, the triangle has very rough edges, not smooth edges, like in the example.

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import MetalKit
import simd

class MBEMetalView: UIView {

     // // // // // MAIN // // // // //
     var metalDevice: MTLDevice! = nil
     var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer! = nil
     var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
     var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer! = nil
     var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState! = nil
     var displayLink: CADisplayLink! = nil

     override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
          return CAMetalLayer.self
     }
//     override func didMoveToWindow() {
//          self.redraw()
//     }
     override func didMoveToSuperview() {
          super.didMoveToSuperview()
          if self.superview != nil {
               self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkFired))
               self.displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .common)
          } else {
               self.displayLink.invalidate()
          }
     }
     @objc func displayLinkFired() {
          self.redraw()
     }





     // // // // // INIT // // // // //
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          self.prepareDeviceLayerAndQueue()
          self.makeBuffers()
          self.makePipeline()
     }

     func prepareDeviceLayerAndQueue() {
          metalLayer = (self.layer as! CAMetalLayer)
          metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
          metalLayer.device = metalDevice
          metalLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
          commandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()
     }

     func makeBuffers() {
          var vertices: [MBEVertex] = [
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(0, 0.5, 0, 1) , color: vector_float4(1, 0, 0, 1)),
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1)  , color: vector_float4(0, 1, 0, 1)),
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(0.5, -0.5, 0, 1)  , color: vector_float4(0, 0, 1, 1))
          ]
          self.vertexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: &vertices, length: 56, options: .storageModeShared)
     }

     func makePipeline() {
          guard let library = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE LIBRARY") ; return }
          guard let vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertex_main") else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A VERTEX FUNCTION") ; return }
          guard let fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_main") else { print("COULD NOT CREATE LIBRARY") ; return }

          let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
          pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
          pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
          pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = metalLayer.pixelFormat

          pipelineState = try? metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
          if pipelineState == nil { print("COULD NOT CREATE PIPELINE STATE") ; return }

     }





     // // // // // FUNCTIONS // // // // //
     func redraw() {
          guard let drawable = metalLayer.nextDrawable() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A DRAWABLE") ; return }
          let texture = drawable.texture
          let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)

          guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A COMMAND BUFFER") ; return }
          guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { print("COULD NOT CREATE AN ENCODER") ; return }

          commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
          commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
          commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3)

          commandEncoder.endEncoding()
          commandBuffer.present(drawable)
          commandBuffer.commit()
     }





     // // // // // TYPES // // // // //
     struct MBEVertex {
          var position: vector_float4
          var color: vector_float4
     }

}
```

I have tried to render the triangle a few different times with different methods (sometimes use a MetalKit view from interface builder, sometimes create the view manually)... each time, though, the triangle comes out with rough edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that the drawable size of your layer is much smaller than the resolution of your screen. You can get them to match by taking the following steps:

When your Metal view moves to a new superview, update its `contentsScale` property to match that of the hosting display:

```
layer.contentsScale = self.window?.screen.scale ?? 1.0
```

Add a property to your view subclass that computes the ideal drawable size based on the bounds of the view and its scale:

```
var preferredDrawableSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: bounds.size.width * layer.contentsScale,
                  height: bounds.size.height * layer.contentsScale)
}
```

Update the `drawableSize` of your layer when you detect that it doesn't match the computed preferred size:

```
 func redraw() {
      if metalLayer.drawableSize != preferredDrawableSize {
          metalLayer.drawableSize = preferredDrawableSize
      }
    ...
 }
```

By the way, these days there's really no good reason not to use `MTKView` for this purpose. It abstracts all of these details for you and is much nicer to work with.

Comment: If you need even smoother edges, you can enable multisampled antialiasing (MSAA). That's tedious when rolling your own Metal view, but trivial when using `MTKView`: `view.sampleCount = 4`.

Comment: True but I think it's really helpful to know what's being done for me just in case I ever want to look deeper into the matter... which I think will always be the case @warrenm

Thanks so much for your help, man. I really want to be able to work with the GPU without struggling.

Comment: Question... How is it possible that "smoother" edges can be made, given that there is a fixed number of pixels (1125 x 2436 in my case)?

Comment: The only way I can imagine would be to modulate the pixels every frame, producing an average image that is perceived to be smoother... is that right @warrenm?

Comment: Many such techniques do exist (keyword: [TSAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing)), but we can get better results within a single frame by increasing the _sampling rate_ near the edges of primitives. Instead of taking one sample, as we're doing when drawing 1:1 with the screen pixels, we take 2, 4, or more samples over the region of our pixel, and average the results to get a smoother result. I recommend this [memo by Alvy Ray Smith](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf) to understand some of the basic issues related to sampling theory as applied to graphics.